# Trying to use ir-keytable with unknown photo-diode for remote control receiver

Tags: lirc

I found a photo-diode and I'm trying to use it to decode the signals from various IR remote control. I managed to connect it to my RPi to get a signal using a busy loop in a python script but now I want to decode those signals using ir-keytable. I edited the /boot/config.txt file, uncommenting dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17. I'm sure I'm using the correct pin as my script no longer works (as the PIN is no longer free for GPIO), but when I launch ir-keytable using that command:

sudo ir-keytable -v -t -p all

nothing happens, and I tried almost all the remote controls in my house. When my script was working, I was able to see a pattern in the signal depending on the button pressed but for some reason, it's not detected as one of the protocols supported by my RPi. I guess it could be related to my wiring or the photo-diode. Do someone has a suggestion to debug/fix that?

I also bought a ir-set-5mm-emitter emitter/receiver pair but I don't know how to use/wire it and it doesn't work with the same wiring as the unknown photo-diode. I even don't know which one is the receiver and/or if they are damaged.

When I saw the result of the busy-loop, I was confident and spoke to my kids of a project that we could do and they are verry enthusiasts, so I just want it to work now.

https://abra-electronics.com/opto-illumination/infrared-optics/5mm-infrared-emitter-and-sensor-set-ir-set-5mm.html

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the signal with piscope. https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html

Comment: Have a look at my question and answer here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753802/321108

Answer (score 0):

I looked how IR receiver modules are built and I saw they have a demodulator and then, I understood the 38 KHz signal was only the envelop and the message is sent by bursts. That's why it cannot work with a simple photo-diode. I guess I will have to buy an IR receiver module. Is there one of them that is known to be more versatile and work for more remote controls?

Thanks!

Comment: `38 KHz signal was only the envelop` ... no, the 38 kHz signal is the carrier ... the data is the envelope ... btw, KHz is Kelvin Hertz ... kilo is lower case k ... also, don't  ask questions inside an answer